# cannot find send to mandrill in templates

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I need to create transactional email, so I created a trial plan from automation.
Now I need to send template to mandrill but I cannot find send to mandrill button from templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in email builder type. I was using new builder which is beta, once I used classic I was able to send template to madrill

You can change email builder from `Account -> Settings-> Details-> Default Email Builder` then choose your builder.

Comment: I have the same issue, but it seems changing to the old builder is not working. I even log out and login again, but the editor looks the same, and no "Send to Mandrill" button

Comment: @GuilhermeMussi you need to create NEW templates after changing that option... this really sucks and i'm shocked more people aren't talking about this.

Comment: @brad not needed. The issue is, it only works for CLASSIC templates, not the new template editor. Had to go through with their support to figure this out...

Comment: yeah it's ridiculous and i don't understand why the NEW one doesn't support OLD features ...